# The multi-part identifier could not be bound. When joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    I.NAME 
FROM 
    All_Items$ AS I, 
    Cost_Model$ AS P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Cost_Model$ ON I.ITEMID = P.ITEMRELATION
```

I am trying to join 2 tables together within the same database. `ItemID` and `ItemRelation` are the same things that are why I'm trying to outer left join but some `itemID` doesn't have corresponding `ItemRelation` in the other table.

Not sure why it says multi-part identifier could not be bound on `I.ITEMID`

Please help.

Comment: Have you verified that you specified the right column names?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Why was this tagged with C# and Visual Studio when it has nothing to do with either?

Comment: im working within visual studio using sql server but youre right it should prob be sql

Comment: Fix the code to use proper join.

Answer (score 0):

You should also select some fields from the Cost_Model$ table, otherwise the LEFT JOIN will simply output all the record of All_Items$.
Try this:

```
SELECT 
    I.NAME, P.SOMETHING
FROM 
    All_Items$ AS I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Cost_Model$ AS P ON I.ITEMID = P.ITEMRELATION
```